# MongoDB 1:0/1 relationship between account and user collections

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am coming from the wonderful world of Relational databases and I am currently wondering how to implement a one-to-one relationship.

Here is the problem:

**Relational Database** : I have 2 tables `Account` and `User` with a 1:0/1 relationship => An `account` record MUST be associated to a user record but a 'user' can be its own entity and not be associated with an `account`.

**NoSQL database** : From my understanding there are 3 main solutions to this problem.

1. Create a `User` collection with a nullable `account` field.

`user = {
    _id: string,
    username: string,
    account: {
        password: string
    }
}`

2. Create a `Account` collection with a `user` field that only contain user associated with accounts + Create a `User` collection table that only contain users without accounts. The problem here is that we duplicate the user fields

`account = {
    _id: string,
    username: string, // duplicated
    password: string
}`

`user = {
    _id: string,
    username: string // duplicated
}`

3. Use a `$lookup` over 2 collections `Account` and `User` with `Account` containing a `userId` field.

`account = {
    _id: string,
    userId: string
}`

`user = {
    _id: string,
    username: string // duplicated
}`

I personally prefer the solution 1 as it feels the more appropriate for a NoSQL database.

Yet I am not convinced and any other solution or feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Its totally opinion based. All depends upon your architecture and what type of queries you are going to fire. Solution 1 is more like non relational Db, where as 2 and 3 are like incorporating relational DB into non relational. The only problem is the complex queries you need to fire with join in solution 2 and 3.

Comment: The first one, if second opinion convince you.

Comment: Thank you for your comments but I was not really looking for opinion based. I searched online for articles regarding the subject but they did not help that much. I was looking for something more reliable. Like the 3rd normal form for relational databases.